# i have created a application which contain first page as login page.I want entered emailid to every page in application

Tags: python, html, django-views

I have created a application which contain first page as login page. My question is that, I want to show the entered `emailid` at the time of login to every page of my application. If I declare `emailid` as global it throwing error. Please tell me any trick if u have.
Thank u!!!

```
def loginbmtool(request):
    emailid=request.POST["emailid"]
    password=request.POST["password"]
    if(str(emailid) == "brisatechnology@gmail.com" and str(password) == "hellobrisa123"):
        msg ="" +emailid
        return  render_to_response('admin.html',{'msg':msg})
##    if(str(emailid) != "brisatechnology@gmail.com" and str(password) = "brisa123"):
##         msg ="" +emailid
##         return  render_to_response('login.html',{'wrong_user':'wrong emailid or password'})
    else:
        print "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        db=validate()
        flag1=db.ValidateUser_Authentication(emailid,password)
        if(flag1=="true"):


            msg ="" +emailid
            db=Fetch()
            list1=db.pendinginvoice()
            list2=db.delayedpay()
            countofpo=db.NewPOs()
            countofinvoice=db.invoicenocount()
            countofacc,m,y=db.NewAccounts()
            y=" "+y
            mon=int(m)
            listofmnth=[]
            listofmnth=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
            month=listofmnth[mon-1]
            expiringPO=db.ExpiringPO()

            print "\ncountofpo",countofpo
            print list2
            print list1
            print list2
            return render_to_response("index.html",{'msg':msg,"month":month,"year":y,"countofacc":countofacc,"expiringPO":expiringPO,"countofinvoice":countofinvoice,"countofpo":countofpo,"list1":list1,"list2":list2,"msg":msg})
        else:

            return render_to_response('login.html',{'wrong_user':'emailid or password you entered is incorrect?'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with python, but if it is for web, it must have some sort of session variable. Have you tried implementing it?

For further reading: http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_session